# Wpf app using Web API -Identity Server 4

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

WPF OidcClient:

```
var options = new 
    {
    //redirect to identity server
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
    ClientId = "native.code",
    Scope = "openid profile email fiver_auth_api",
    //redirect back to app if auth success
    RedirectUri = "http://127.0.0.1/sample-wpf-app",
    ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.FormPost, 
    Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
    Browser = new WpfEmbeddedBrowser()
};
```

WPF calling web api :

```
private void CallButtonAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = token;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        //on button click call Web api Get movies
        //Initialize HTTP Client 
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/movies/get").Result;
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Movies not Found");
        }

    }
```

Identity Server - WPF declared as client
    //wpf desktop app

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "native.code",
    ClientName = "Native Client (Code with PKCE)",

    RedirectUris = { "http://127.0.0.1/sample-wpf-app" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000" },

    RequireClientSecret = false,
    RequireConsent = true,

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "fiver_auth_api"
    },
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    IdentityTokenLifetime=3600,

}
```

The web api can be used just when a user is authorize. I got the token in the wpf app but when is calling the web api i got back a 401(unauthorize).

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered using the IdentityModel Nuget package (DiscoveryClient, etc.)?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. Start by check the log of IdentityServer.

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/Wpf   I start using this repo. I cheked the Identity Server and that is ok. I do receive the token in the WPF app but when I access the web api i get back a 401.

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin I have the same issue, could you please say how have you fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

My best is that you are missing the

`AllowOfflineAccess = true`

when [defining the Client at the IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/8f68a5258b81741847ae06c02f65423d67147cf5/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs#L81)

Comment: review your configurations - match it with the sample - there are a lot of inconsistencies in your edits (e.g. in Client there is localhost vs 127.0.0.1) - the sample code I linked to works fine...